# Execute commit window in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

When I go to commit a change in Android Studio (I am using git), the `Commit Changes` dialogue box shows up and asks for a commit message.
After typing in the message, I cannot figure out a way to execute the commit without clicking the `Commit` button with the mouse.

This is a minor complaint, but it consistently frustrates me that I can't use <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd> or something like it as a shortcut to execute the dialogue box.

Edit: Does anyone know how to map this to <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd> instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd> is usually how you do this on a Mac, but Android Studio for whatever reason uses the Windows version in this case:

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>